# How can I resolve timeout errors in SSIS around midnight every night?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I find a pair of these in my Application Event Log a little after midnight every night:

> The SSIS Execution Process could not write to the IS catalog:
>   *MyServerName*:SSISDB Error details: Unable to add new messages to the
>   table of operation messages.:Timeout expired. The timeout period
>   elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not
>   responding.; at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ISServerHelper.AppendEventMessage(SqlCommand
>   cmd, Int64 operationId, Int32 message_type, DateTimeOffset
>   message_time, Int16 message_source, String message_text, Nullable`1
>   extendedInfoId, String packageName, String packageLocationType, String
>   packagePathFull, String eventName, String messageSource, String
>   messageSrcId, String subComponentName, String packagePath, String
>   executionPath, UInt32 threadId, Nullable`1 messageCode, Int64&
>   eventMessageId) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.BasicEventInfo.WriteInternal(SqlCommand
>   sqlCommand) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.Loggable.Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ILoggable.Write(SqlConnection
>   conn)

Searching the web for various parts of the error message failed to turn up anything useful.

There is an Agent job that runs **SSISDB.internal.cleanup_server_retention_window** at midnight every night, and Confio Ignite shows me that it blocks for about 6 minutes every time it runs. It blocks a couple of executions from **SSIS ISServerExec** of **SSISDB.internal.append_event_message** with LCK_M_IX waits.

I'm not sure which procedure is timing out, or if the timeout is from something unrelated. Is this a known issue (I'm running SQL Server 2012 SP1 Standard Edition (no CU installed)? Is there a good workaround?

Comment: What's your patch level? Have you seen Phil's post on the [matter](http://www.ssistalk.com/2013/01/31/ssis-2012-catalog-indexing-recommendations/)?

Comment: I'm running SQL Server 2012 SP1 Standard Edition (no CU installed). I haven't seen Phil's post, so thanks for the pointer. The KB is confusing - it says that the new indexes are part of CU4 and CU7, which implies that they aren't in CU5 and CU6. That doesn't fit with how I understood the CUs to work (each contains everything in the previous ones).

Comment: It looks like the recently released [SP2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2014/06/11/sql-server-2012-sp2-is-now-available.aspx) replaces everything up through SP1 CU9, so I'll just upgrade to that.

Comment: Sing out once you've applied SP2 and let us know if it fixes things.

Comment: Will do. It may be a while though. Getting authorization to take the instance down will be difficult and time-consuming. There is no defined maintenance window.

Comment: Did you found any resolution to above issue? Our job is failing and we also see similar message in logs.

Comment: Sadly, I am *still* trying to get a maintenance window to install SP2.

Comment: What I did in the meanwhile was to gradually decrease the RETENTION_WINDOW for the SSISDB catalog by one week at a time (which caused the next cleanup job execution to take several hours) until I got it down to where the cleanup job stopped throwing errors.